# Change Zabbix server housekeeping parameters via script

Tags: zabbix

I want to automate Zabbix server deployment and change default [housekeeping parameters](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/web_interface/frontend_sections/administration/general)  from bash script. I want to avoid doing it manualy from Web GUI.
Is there API or some other way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no API support for changing these parameters, but you can change them directly in the database, table `config`. See the parameters that start with `hk_` at http://zabbix.org/wiki/Docs/DB_schema/3.0/config .